# Core Data returning NSArrays instead of NSStrings

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray

For some reason all of the NSString typed attributes are being returned as NSArrays in my Article object.  Here's my function to retrieve them:

```
- (NSArray *)getSavedArticles
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last_opened" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSort]];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

I have not created a NSManagedObjectModel for these, and instead I'm just accessing them using KVO.

```
//self.data has the array returned from getSavedArticles
NSManagedObject *object = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
NSString *path  = [object valueForKey:@"path"];
NSString* id      = [object valueForKey:@"id"];
```

When I look at this in the variables pane, on `path` and `id` I see `(__NSArrayI *) ... Variable is not a CFString.` Printing the description of either of these also prints out the parenthesis used when printing arrays.

I'm just wondering if this could be due to the sort descriptor? I have double checked that the data going into these objects is typed correctly, and the SQLite database that I'm using to backup everything is displaying strings.

I have tried re-installing the app in the simulator, and resetting it. I still get a NSArray instead of a NSString.

I really don't know what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I just found something else interesting. I do another check to see if an Article has been saved, and this time I don't get a NSArray for the article path:

```
- (NSString *)hasArticleSaved:(NSString *)id
{
    NSString *path = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"id", id]];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects.count > 0) {
       NSManagedObject *savedArticle = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [savedArticle valueForKey:@"path"];
    }
    return path;
}
```

Now I'm really confused. Any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had changed the data structure for my table so self.data is an array of arrays...and with only 1 object it looked like I was getting a NSArray back when in fact I was just accessing the data wrong. I just needed to do `[[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
[self.data objectForKey:indexPath.row]
```

...because `objectForKey:` is looking for a string key name e.g. "path" or "id". Giving it an integer will produce an error or a random return.

Instead, you want:

```
[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

... which will return the managed object at the given index in the array.

Comment: Whoops! That's a typo in the question. I am using objectAtIndex. Fixing now.